# Breadth-first-search on 2D array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, breadth-first-search, undirected-graph

I have a grid of connected paths as shown below:
 [image]

The grid is a 2D array created as follows:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        hz[x] = new Array(10);

        for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            hz[x][y] = new block(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Each element of the array contains an object of type `block` as follows:

```
function block(top, bottom, left, right, visited){
    this.top = top;
    this.bottom = bottom;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.visited = visited;
}
```

I have implemented a breadth-first-search on my grid in order to define the connected components. I need it to be completely connected. This is my code for the BFS:

```
function search(){
    var count = 0;
    var graph = hz;

    for(var x=0; x < 9; x++){
        for(var y=0; y < 9; y++){
            if(!graph[x][y].visited){ //if block not yet visited
                count++;
                q = new Queue();
                q.enqueue(graph[x][y]);
                graph[x][y].visited = 1;

                while(q.size() > 0){
                    var w = q.dequeue();
                    var ends = numberOfEnds(w);
                    var a = w.x;
                    var b = w.y;

                    for(var t=0; t < ends; t++){
                        if(w.left){
                            if(graph[a][b-1].right){
                                if(!graph[a][b-1].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].left = 0;
                                    graph[a][b-1].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a][b-1]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if(w.right){
                            if(graph[a][b+1].left){
                                if(!graph[a][b+1].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].right = 0;
                                    graph[a][b+1].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a][b+1]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (w.top){
                            if(graph[a-1][b].bottom){
                                if(!graph[a-1][b].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].top = 0;
                                    graph[a-1][b].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a-1][b]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (w.bottom){
                            if(graph[a+1][b].top){
                                if(!graph[a+1][b].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].bottom = 0;
                                    graph[a+1][b].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a+1][b]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } //end for every neighbour of block
                } //end while

            } //end if visited
        } //end for y
    } //end for x

    console.log("Count: " + count);
}
```

The problem is that when I run the algorithm, the result of `count` is very high, like in the 50s when it should be 1 or 2 at the most.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the code `count` is a simple integral counter, but you say it reaches a value of 50 seconds. This is inconsistent: what are you really measuring and what is the basis for it being only "1 or 2"?

Comment: you're using the `x,y` of the starting node all the way, instead you should use the `x,y` of the dequeued nodes

Comment: @Richard *in the fifties* - there are no seconds

Comment: @BeyelerStudios , how do I change the `x,y` values? Should I update them at the end of the `for(t)` loop?

Comment: You don't change those `x,y` otherwise you'll destroy your outer loops, instead you have to either store the position in each node or store a new object in the queue like: `q.enqueue({node:graph[x][y], x:x, y:y})` and use `w.node, w.x, w.y` in your search.

Comment: Okay, got it. Last question: do I update all the `x,y` values inside the `while()` loop and leave those outside it the same?

Comment: I'd say yes, but I don't really understand your idea with the `for(t)` loop, maybe you could elaborate or rethink that first: what is `t` really used for in the loop body? Why not remove all the `else` instead?

Comment: Looking at the pseudocode of the breadth-first-search, it says that for every element that is dequeued, you need to look at all of its adjacent elements. So the `for(t)` loop runs for the number of connections that the current block has and enqueues each of those blocks in turn. I just need to do a bunch of extra checks because if a block has `left=1` then the block to the left of it must also have `right=1` for them to be considered connected.

Comment: Yes, you have up to 4 connections, you already check them with individual if statements, what is the `for` loop for exactly? Just get rid of it. (This is maybe a simple misuse of `else if` in your case.)

Comment: Great, you're right. It was unnecessary. Took it away and changed the `else if`s to `if`s. Thanks, it works now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the comments given, this is the code for the answer:

```
function search(){
    var count = 0;
    var graph = hz;

    for(var x=0; x < 9; x++){
        for(var y=0; y < 9; y++){
            if(!graph[x][y].visited){ //if block not yet visited
                count++;
                console.log("Component: " + count);
                q = new Queue();
                q.enqueue(graph[x][y]);
                graph[x][y].visited = 1;

                while(q.size() > 0){
                    var w = q.dequeue();
                    var ends = numberOfEnds(w);
                    var a = w.x;
                    var b = w.y;


                        if(w.left){
                            if(graph[a][b-1].right){
                                if(!graph[a][b-1].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].left = 0;
                                    graph[a][b-1].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a][b-1]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(w.right){
                            if(graph[a][b+1].left){
                                if(!graph[a][b+1].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].right = 0;
                                    graph[a][b+1].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a][b+1]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (w.top){
                            if(graph[a-1][b].bottom){
                                if(!graph[a-1][b].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].top = 0;
                                    graph[a-1][b].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a-1][b]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (w.bottom){
                            if(graph[a+1][b].top){
                                if(!graph[a+1][b].visited){
                                    graph[a][b].bottom = 0;
                                    graph[a+1][b].visited = 1;
                                    q.enqueue(graph[a+1][b]);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                } //end while

            } //end if visited
        } //end for y
    } //end for x

    console.log("Count: " + count);
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: This is the final answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, mistake I found is when you are checking neighbours of current block you are going only in one direction till you are having a neighbour in that direction, By doing so you missed putting some of the neighbours in the queue and when you reach them by your outermost loop they are considered as new connected component,and your counter is incremented again for the same component.

My solution to this mistake is just change "else if" to "if" i.e. if any block is connected to current block put it in the queue.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind adding the code snippets to clarify the solution for fellow programmers.

Comment: code will be the same as in problem statement except in function **search** you have to replace **else if** by **if**.